# Check dynamic Bootstrap Table for class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So i got this table

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" class="hidden">ID</th>
            <th data-field="variant">Variant</th>
            <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

it will be filled with data trough

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: returnValue
});
```

then i can click the rows which will add the class `.bg-info` to it and i want to check if a row has the class and then save the row data in a `var`

this was my attempt:

```
var item = $.map(table.rows('.bg-info').data(), function (item) {
    return item[0]
});
```

but table.rows can't be used as a method apparently

Comment: what's in table and how it's defined

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the rows with the class `bg-info` in your table. Use a jQuery selector based on that class :

```
var bgInfoRows = $("#table tbody .bg-info");
```

You will have every item in tbody that has the class `bg-info`.